# Angular 8 - ng e2e doesn't work with default chrome driver

Tags: protractor, angular8

[image]

I have angular 8 and I want to run protractor for the e2e testing in which when I am running 
**`protractor protractor.conf.js`** command it's taking default chrome driver from **`node_modules`**

But when I run ng e2e it's giving the error shown in the picture.

I have the ***Angular version - 8.3.8*** & **Protractor version - 5.4.2** & **Chrome version - 79.0.3945.88**

Comment: It looks like your Chrome and ChromeDriver major versions do not match. This is probably why ChromeDriver is failing to launch Chrome.

Comment: @Vishal have you fixed this?

Answer (score 0):

When you run ng e2e, webdriver-manager update is run by default. You can try using the `ng e2e --no-webdriver-update` flag. But before that you will need to run webdriver-update manually. Add these to your scripts.

```
 "scripts": {
    "debug": "node --inspect-brk ./node_modules/.bin/protractor protractor.conf.js",
    "pretest": "npm run tsc && npm run webdriver-update",
    "test": "./node_modules/protractor/bin/protractor protractor.conf.js",
    "e2e": "npm run tsc && ./node_modules/protractor/bin/protractor protractor.conf.js",
    "tsc": "./node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc",
    "webdriver-update": "./node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update --standalone --versions.standalone=3.8.0 --chrome --versions.chrome=78.0.3904.97",
  }
```

You don't need the npm run tsc command if you are not using typescript. Remove it before execution. The webdriver-update command will fix update the chrome to version 78 and standalone to 3.8.0. This should work.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is, that the `webdriver-manager`, which is a dependency from protractor is too old. Make sure to update it regularly as it is locked by `package-lock.json` or `yarn.lock`.

Use `yarn upgrade` or `npm update` to update the minor/patch versions and transitive dependencies.